# ODP.NET updated to latest version, now all exceptions say "Message 20105 not found"

Tags: oracle, odp.net, ifs

In an .NET 4.5.1 application that I have written which connects to an oracle database using the latest version ODP.net (12c I think) I no longer get the error messages from exceptions. No matter what happens it just says "Message 20105 not found" or something similar. I used to get messages that said something useful like "Active.Separate object does not exist" or something like that. I know these error messages are not standard messages from Oracle but they are given when an exception is thrown from the stored procedures I call used by IFS.

If I use the 11 version of the ODP.net this works properly.

If I cannot find out how to get those error messages I have to go back to the 11 version, but I'd prefer not too.

Comment: Did you rebuild your app with the 12.1 ODP.NET? Did you install 12.1 ODP.NET using the installer into a new oracle home (directory)? When I google ORA-20105 I get "unable to move AWR data to SYS".

Comment: Yes, rebuilt with 12.1 ODP.NET, used both the installer, and also the ODAC XCopy installer. THe complete error message is: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-20105: Message 20105 not found;  product=RDBMS; facility=ORA